# I did *not* retract my vote

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes, close-dialog

I flagged / voted to close a question as duplicate. It did get closed for that. Someone else reopened the question. I tried to flag / close it as duplicate again but I can't and I'm told:

> You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote

That is not true. I didn't retract my vote.

[image: partial screenshot]

Comment: Cross-site report (MSE): [When a retraction is not a retraction. Please update close-menu message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376335/when-a-retraction-is-not-a-retraction-please-update-close-menu-message) - The message is just wrong and it is being reviewed.

Comment: @animuson Ah yes, I had [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+cannot+vote+to+close+again+after+retracting+your+vote%22) but that only showed three results and that other question wasn't among them.

Comment: @animuson Should I delete mine? And perhaps add the phrase as text to that other question, so that Google finds it?

Comment: @KellyBundy cross-site duplicates are perfectly OK, please do keep it - not every user on SO visits the big Meta - your report is useful as it will allow you or us close new such reports against it (which is impossible with cross-site dupes).

Comment: For the record, you wouldn't be able to close the question again anyway. Your close vote needs to expire even though the question is reopened,only then would you be able to close vote again.